# Navigation bar error in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and I need help with the navigation bar. I need to get the sub-topic right under the ABOUT US part but I cannot get it, it appears all the way to the right. Anything would be appreciated.
I can provide the HTML file if you need.

CSS:

```
container{
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 1100px;
}

.masthead{
    background: #039be5;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 90px;
    font-family: Josefin Slab;
    font-size: 21px;
    top: 17px;

}
.logo h1 a {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }

h1{
    margin: 0;
}

a:link    {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }
a:visited {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }
a:hover   {color: white;  color: black; }
a:active  {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }

#navcontent{
    word-spacing: 4px;
}

li{
    position: relative;
    left: 155px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Raleway;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 21px; 
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navigation{
    float: right;
}

.navigation ul>li ul{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}

.navigation ul>li ul>li{
    bottom: 0px;
    display: none;
}

.navigation>ul>li:hover ul>li{
    display: block;
}

.navigation>ul>li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="index.htm"> MY SITE</a></h1>

        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="courses.htm">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="institution.htm">Places</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.htm">More</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Share</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Help</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="navcontent">||<a href="signin.htm"> Sign In </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="signup.htm">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh8fcyja/)

Comment: Some `html` would help us help you, context is always good.

Comment: Jon P. : http://pastebin.com/MFfESYKf

Comment: Thanks Jon. Didn't want it to looked messed up, so used pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the point,,

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
}
ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}
ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}
ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}
ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}
ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}
ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

[Live result here](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/L2sa2vd4/).
Hope this help

**UPDATE**

Ok, due to what Jon P ask I will describe this code.
Actually the main keys are :

```
ul ul
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background:#fff; /*remove, no effect*/ 
  padding:0 /*remove, no effect*/
}
```

First, we make the child(`<ul>`) become hidden with `display: none` and give it properties `position:absolute, top:100%, left:0;` to let it under the `MORE` link

And then what we want? show it when we hover the `MORE` link. to do so, just do simple by making that child(`<ul>`) visible. Of course, we use this property :

```
ul li:hover > ul
{
  display:block
}
```

Comment: I hope you're going to add some clarification, I hate answers that are just a big slab of code. Let them know what they did wrong and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Aldi : why ul ul ul ? I dont have 3 of it used ?

Comment: @Sooner I am sorry. if so, just delete. I just copied from my project which has same case with you

Comment: Aldi: Oh ok, but the thing is i am having this difficulty.

Comment: the dropped down text are not in position.

Comment: By the way, sorry for my bad english :)